# CMake library adjacent subdir dependency

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies

I've the following directory structure

```
A                                  # produces libA
  CMakeLists.txt
  includes
    file.h
  sources
    file.cpp
B                                  # produces libB depends on libA
  CMakeLists.txt
  includes
     ...
  sources
     ...
app                                # produces executable, depends on libA and libB
  CMakeLists.txt
  includes
    ...
  sources
    ...
```

I want both `libA.so` and `libB.so` be independently available and usable by other applications as well as `app`.

What is the clean way to manage this using CMake.

in `A/CMakeLists.txt`

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes)
...
ADD_LIBRARY(a SHARED ${A_SOURCES})
```

in `B/CMakeLists.txt`

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes)
ADD_sUBDIRECTORY(../A)
# ^^^ This wont work
...
ADD_LIBRARY(b SHARED ${B_SOURCES})
```

Same problem will occur in `app/CMakeLists.txt` You cannot ADD_SUBDIRECTORY a sibling

I don't want to hardcode paths with explicit directory names. I think I am not alone more people have faced the same. So what is the regularly practiced solution for this ?

Should I place `A/a.cmake` and `B/b.cmake` and declare `A_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `B_INCLUDE_DIRS`. but again A is not a sub directory of B

If I make `B/a.cmake`, `app/a.cmake` and `app/b.cmake` files and `SET` variables `INCLUDE_DIRS` there and include them in their CMakeLists.txt ? But is this the standard way to solve this problem ? or would this even work ?

**Problem 2**

Another thing I've tried to place a `main.cpp` and `CMakeLists.txt` on root (e.g. parent of app, a, b). There I can `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(A)` easily as its really a subdirectory. I did

```
SET(A_INCLUDE_DIRS
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes
)
```

on `A/CMakeLists.txt`. and expected to get that variable in root/CMakeLists.txt, which didn't work. But it works If I use `PARENT_SCOPE` or `SCOPE` with `SET` But I don't know whether this is okay to configure such a way or its a hack ?

Answer (score 0):

You need the top level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory(A)
add_subdirectory(B)
add_subdirectory(app)
```

and inside `app/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(app ...)
target_link_libraries(app A B)
```

Comment: How will B link to libA. If I try to build B only ? and how and where will I get A_INCLUDE_DIRS Variable set ?

Comment: @DiproSen Change the order, first add subdirectory B then you library target B to link: `target_link_libraries(A B)`

Comment: `and how and where will I get A_INCLUDE_DIRS Variable set?` You can add command `include_directories(A)` in top CMake file or use `target_inlude_directories(A PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}")` in directory A, this will automatically add headers location when you link library A to your application.